# Kotlin and use padEnd() twice

Tags: string, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

I tried using [`padEnd()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-end.html) twice on a `String`. The first time the `padEnd()` extension function works as expected, but the second time, it does not add the any characters I tried.

My code:

```
var s = "Hi -> "
s = s.padEnd(10, 'O')
s = s.padEnd(5, ' ')
println(s)
```

My output:

```
Hi -> OOOO
```

I am using kotlin version 1.2.50. I also tried [Jetbrains' online compiler](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt) to prevent the bug being only on my computer, with the same result. I also tried using a different version of kotlin (1.0.7 and 1.1.60), with still the same feature/bug.

I also tried using the `padStart()`, with the same behaviour, just adding it in front of the `String`.

Mixing the two extension functions also did not work as expected: Using `padStart()` and immediately after that `padEnd()`

Is this an expected feature? If so why is it expected? Or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`padEnd` doesn't add the given character to your String the given number of times - the first parameter is the target length that it will pad up to. From the docs:

> Returns a char sequence of length at least `length` consisting of this char sequence appended with `padChar` as many times as are necessary to reach that length.

So in your second call, you're trying to pad `"Hi -> 0000"` until it's at least 5 characters long - which it already is, so no spaces are added at its end.

Comment: I tried changing the example as you suggested `s = s.padEnd(20, ' ')` being the last line of my code, with the same result. Nothing changed

Comment: Ok sorry, I forgot that I added the spaces, and did not manage to see them :D

Comment: A fun thing to debug by just looking at the output for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like:

```
val outerChar =  "*"
val x = outerChar.padEnd(10)
        .plus("hello")
        .plus(outerChar.padStart(10))
println(x)

// Prints:
// *         hello         *
```

This will put 10 spaces between the * and hello on each side. Also try swapping the calls to padEnd and padStart.